# react: непонятный waring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

В проекте стали вылезать вот такие предупреждения:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/react-zoom-pan-pinch/dist/index.esm.js
>
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> Failed to parse source map from
> 'D:\sites\test\node_modules\react-zoom-pan-pinch\src\utils\calculations.utils.ts'
> file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'D:\sites\test\node_modules\react-zoom-pan-pinch\src\utils\calculations.utils.ts'

Т.е. предупреждения в терминале Visual Studio Code а не в консоли браузера

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить? Вроде только библиотеку Ant Design установил и все

Comment: Создайте отдельный проект с нуля. Устанавливайте все пакеты один за другим которые как вам кажется могут вызвать ошибку в терминале и наблюдайте. Удачного дебаггинга :)

Comment: @randall И что это даст? ворнинг не для моего кода, значит я никак повлиять на него не могу, выход - замена модуля, но опять же - это не всегда возможно, т.е. надо как-то просто блокировать сообщение или что-то подобное делать

Comment: Вы найдете ошибку, и поймете какой пакет вызывает эту ошибку. После этого устранить ошибку не составит труда.